# Read process memory event

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm reading data out of a process in the memory. Works as intended. Right now I'm just running the code in a timer to check for changes.

I would like to know if there is any way to create an event that triggers as soon as the memory changes on a certain adress (which I obviously know). I'm not a big fan of the whole timer solution.

```
private static extern bool ReadProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, 
                             UIntPtr lpBaseaddress, [Out] byte[] lpBuffer, 
                             UIntPtr nSize, IntPtr lpNumberOfBytesRead);

public static int ReadInt(long address)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[sizeof(int)];
    ReadProcessMemory(PHandle, (UIntPtr)address, buffer, (UIntPtr)4, 
                                                                 IntPtr.Zero);
    return BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer, 0);
}
```

Comment: I feel the `unsafe` keyword coming on!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theoretically there is — it's called a data breakpoint — but there is no public API for setting them. [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28071/Toggle-hardware-data-read-execute-breakpoints-prog) is how it can sort of be done directly, but you'd be better off looking at leveraging WinDbg or ADPlus or other existing debuggers. Messing with the CPU's debug registers is a quick and painless way to BSOD.

Comment: Thank you. Not the answer I was hoping for, though :|